# What is the difference between module Processing and Multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

There are two modules for Python that have an almost identical layout in terms of methods and purpose. Is one preferred over the other or do they actually perform differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiprocessing is a standard Python library.

If I had to guess, I'd say that Processing (which hasn't been updated since early 2008) became Multiprocessing — but don't quote me on that.

Comment: I was wondering exactly that. The similarity is striking. I'll stick with multiprocessing unless I hear otherwise.